# Text Formatting in PDF Reader and Writer in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, core-graphics

In my application I have to show a PDF reader (PDF from a server) and copy everything to another PDF. I am using [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader/) to show the PDF.

But it is unable to format the text inside the PDF. **Bold** text is shown in some different narrow font other than Bold. Can you please give me a solution?

Again, while writing I am using [Saving a PDF document to disk using Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780745/saving-a-pdf-document-to-disk-using-quartz). But here I am facing the same problem. The new PDF is showing the font other than what is used in the source PDF.

I tried the code below also. Still I am getting the same O/P. Please help me with this. I have not tested it with another text font like italic / underline. It should work for these fonts also.

```
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath {
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, NULL);
  BOOL done = NO;

  do {
    //Start a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
    CGRect paperSize = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(CGPDFDocumentGetPage (pdf, 1), kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, paperSize.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0); 
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
    done = YES;
  } while (!done);

  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

It is happening if the source PDF is generated from a source other than an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The font you're looking to display is not in any of the `iOS devices`, nor is it embedded in the PDF.  Thus, it substitutes a font it thinks is similar.
2. You don't have to use Reader to display a PDF, you can use a web view, the `UIDocumentInteraction` Controller, or `CGPDFController`.  You might have more luck using one of these built-in displays, rather than Reader.